# Updating package under eclipse

Tags: ros, ide, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have added another source file in my package and run some commands like in the answer in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2336/code-completion-problem-with-eclipse-galileo) link (by running "make clean; make eclipse-project command and restart Eclipse"). However, the working package is not updated under eclipse.

I know that it will work out of the box, if I again go through the import package procedure, but, it is tiring doing it every time I add some new files in the package.

Is there any elegant way of doing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12432/updating-package-under-eclipse/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-22**:
@DimitriProsser: There is no error but second source file that I've just added in the package is not updated in eclipse project tree. I simply cannot see it. Am I missing something?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-22**:
What are the errors that you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Click on the Eclipse project tree for your package and press F5. This will update the Eclipse package manager.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-22**:
By the way, just for sharing, I've press F5 before but not clicking to the "Eclipse project tree for your package" prior to press it. Luckily, got an eclipse expert like you here.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-22**:
You really made my day :-) Thanks a lot for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apart from the solution mentioned by Dimitri, it is also sometimes necessary to update Eclipse's index for the contextual help to work (right click on project -> Index -> Rebuild / Freshen with modified files / Freshen all files). Could help you some day too.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-22**:
Thanks for the sharing!